# ASP.NET Web API get dto from body with interface type

Tags: c#, asp.net, oop, inheritance, interface

I want to create a `[HTTPPOST]` controller method. As you can see below, I have a class with two properties of type `IBaseClass`. That's because these properties can be either of type `MyClassA` or `MyClassB`.

I got my dtos like this:

```
public MyDtoToGet {
    public int MyId {get;set;}
    public IBaseClass base1 {get;set;}
    public IBaseClass base2 {get;set;}
}

public interface IBaseClass {
    public int Id {get;set;}
}

public class MyClassA : IBaseClass {
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public string PropertyA {get;set;}
}

public class MyClassB : IBaseClass {
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public int PropertyB {get;set;}
}
```

And my controller looks like this:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Post([FromBody]MyDtoToGet myDtoToGet)
{
    // Problem here -> myDtoToGet is null!
}
```

I guess that there is a problem deserializing the `IBaseClass` properties of `MyDtoToGet` in the JSON. A `[HTTPGET]` works fine.
Since I've never done something like this before I got no clue what I do wrong...

Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: How is the deserializer going to guess which type to use? DTOs are supposed to be simple. JSON itself knows nothing about inheritance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by accepting an `JObject` instead of an `MyDtoToGet` from the JSON body. Then I manually converted the type of the interfaces to the correct type. At the end I created a new object and added the converted objects.

Thanks anyways.

Comment: Can you please paste your updated code , like how you converted into JObject.. I am facing similar issue

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get data in the form of `MyDtoToGet` class. The JSON should be in following format. The reason you got `null` is because of invalid json format being passed.

```
{
    "MyId": 1,
    "base1": {
        "Id": 2,
        "PropertyA": "any string"
    },
    "base2": {
        "Id": 3,
        "PropertyA": "any string"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to not forget to set 'content-type: application/json' header to your request, and that json format of you data matches to your DTO.

Best to try with simple DTO for start.